# Search and replace name in cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, virus

I really need your help I got the virus Win32/Delf.NRJ in my hard drive that add the letter "g" to the beginning of name of the file and hide the file and change the attribute to system so I need to run `attrib -s -r -a -h /D /S` to unhide it.

If I can run some search with cmd or powershell on all the drive and every exe file that start with "g" and hiding, remove is attributes and remove the "g" and unhide it?

I have a lot of exe in this drive and it will take for ever to go through all the files (full 2TB)

Thanks

Comment: No you do not! First of all you have not mentioned the archive attribute, so I'm not at all sure if you should be clearing it. Secondly, there is no need to use the `/D` option with `attrib.exe`, because you're not dealing with directories, only files.

Comment: As an additional note, you'll probably want to do this run As administrator, _(elevated)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden,System` to discover hidden files with the `System` attribute set:

```
$affectedExecutables = Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden,System -Filter g*.exe -Recurse
```

You can use the `-replace` regex operator with `Rename-Item` to remove the `g` from the name, like this:

```
$renamedExecutables = $affectedExecutables |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^g' } -PassThru
```

Finally, PowerShell allows you to modify the file attributes directly:

```
$systemHiddenAttributes = [System.IO.FileAttributes]'Hidden,System'
$renamedExecutables |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bxor $systemHiddenAttributes
}
```

This will remove the Hidden and System attributes from the files